# python function definition to solve equations

Tags: python, function, return, equation, fsolve

```
def fun(z):
   g = np.zeros(4 * N)
   for i in range(4 * N):
       f = np.zeros(4 * N)
       for j in range(4 * N):
            if z[j] != 0:
                f[i] = f[i] + M_kk[i][j] * z[j] * np.arcsinh(w_c / z[j])
            else:
                f[i] = f[i]
       g[i] = f[i] - z[i]
       return(g)

z = fsolve(fun,np.zeros(4 * N))
```

I want to define a function with 4*N equations. Do I put the return(g) at the right position in the end?

Comment: You almost never want to have `return` in a loop like that: the loop only runs through one iteration

Comment: maybe you want a `yield g` ... its hard to tell though